# ARIA for a select list that filters table rows?

Tags: javascript, html, wai-aria

I'm using a select list to filter the visibility of rows in a table. I know that I can add/remove the aria-hidden attribute on the rows. I'm looking for how to properly associate the select list with the table - using ARIA, how to say "this select list filters these rows" ...

Answer (score -2):

To the select element, I added attribute aria-controls="idOfTable". Also, I added a wrapper surrounding the select and table:

```
<div role="form">
```